# Storyboard Safe Area wrong/fixed width for any device

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

After some rearrangement of the views in a view controller in storyboard, the safe area in that specific view controller became bugged. For any device I select the safe area never update its frame width.

In the gif below, I have the Safe Area selected in the document outline to illustrate that.

[image]

When run in a device, the safe area works as expected. So this is an Interface Builder specific problem. Doing a Cmd+Shift+K Clean and deleting Derived Data is not working.

So, is there a known method to rescue that view controller other than recreate it in a new one?

Comment: I am experiencing same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Same issue with me. I have not found workaround yet.

Comment: For me the larger iPad size works fine. Not what I want, but at least layout looks okay in storyboard.

Comment: XCode 12.4 - this bug is still there. XCode - is just full of bugs piece of sift... just desperate of its quality...

Answer (score 7):

I recently had the same issue. 
The way I resolved the issue was I selected the "Safe Area" in the storyBoard navigator.

[image: storyBoard navigator]

After that I used the restraint controls and choose reset to suggested constraints.

[image: restraint controls]

Answer (score 5):

This bug happens if a UIStackView contains at least one multi-line UILabel without an explicit preferred width. I have found no easy workaround that succeeds in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tip how to debug these issues: Turn off the "Installed" checkbox on individual views in your scene until the problem goes away. By process of elimination you can identify which control or constraint is causing problems.

[image]